# Programmatically configure Jersey Application

Tags: java, rest, initialization, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to configure my Jersey application using my own Application implementation or an extended ResourceConfig or PackageResourceConfig. So, my first attempt consists in porting an exisiting web.xml (actually I'm using web-fragment.xml because of library nature of my development) configuration to MyApplication implementation.

This is the working web-fragment.xml before porting

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.pkg.resources;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>my.pkg.Filter1;my.pkg.Filter2</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Below, modified web-fragment.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my.pkg.MyApplication</servlet-name> <!-- implementation follows -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my.pkg.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and MyApplication class

```
// [...]

public class MyApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

@Context
ServletConfig config

public MyApplication() {

    super("my.pkg.resources;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs");

    super.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    // filters not set
}

@PostConstruct 
public void readInitParams() {

    // read init params from ServletConfig

    // config.getInitParameterNames();
    // ...
}

}
```

Anytime I use the second version, I receive the following

```
mag 27, 2013 12:08:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  aero.aice.jerico.rs;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;
mag 27, 2013 12:08:03 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder <init>
INFO: Instantiated the Application class my.package.MyApplication. The following root resource and provider classes are registered: [class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver, class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper, class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider, class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper, class aero.aice.jerico.rs.service.OperationService, class aero.aice.jerico.rs.service.CrudService, class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider]
mag 27, 2013 12:08:03 PM com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider
SEVERE: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver

mag 27, 2013 12:08:04 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: The class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver is a not a public class and cannot be instantiated.
  SEVERE: The inner class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver is not a static inner class and cannot be instantiated.
```

As you can see, `com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver` is the first registered class but that is not instantiable because it is not public and not a static inner class.
I have found very little documentation about this procedure and in particular, how to set features and properties during initialization.
I am using the last available version of Jersey (1.17.1) but have tested with 1.9 too.
Is it also possible to set application path, programatically? I have seen @ApplicationPath in documentation but it is not useful for my purpose because i need to set it at runtime.
I know these are more questions but I think they all lead to the same root.
Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: In addition, I have seen that, using standard ServletContainer in web.xml, PackagesResourceConfig scans the same packages but it does not register com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver, so no exception raises.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no jersey libs on path which is scanned for resource classes.

Base URI you can set only during deployment. Using war name or `@ApplicationPath`. You can override it using `servlet-mapping` element in the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had go through similar problem:

```
SEVERE: The class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver is a not a public class and cannot be instantiated.
SEVERE: The inner class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$1WadlContextResolver is not a static inner class and cannot be instantiated.
```

This error freaked me out... Basically I am using GlassFish 3.x. It has already one jersey.core.jar included. But I needed a jersey-server lib. My libs was:

```
 jersey.core.jar -> MANIFEST.MF -> 1.11.1
 jersey-server-1.17.1
```

My problem was I mixed JARs from different Jersey versions. When I go for jersey-server-1.11.1 I don't see this error anymore.